# How to escape field name in orientdb

Tags: orientdb, orientdb-2.1

I'm having a class with fields like `from` and `to` in an orientdb database.

How do I execute a query that select the `from` and `to` fields?

I tried `select [from] from Activity` but it is complaining about `[`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to disable the strictSql using this command:

```
ALTER DATABASE custom strictSql=false
```

and then you have to use the backtick:

```
SELECT `from` FROM Activity
```

Comment: The backtick worked but I did not execute the `Alter Database`. Maybe it is already false. Is there an sql I can execute the check the current value?

Comment: Look at the DB's tab, at the end of the page you'll see the option strictSql and if is true or false

Comment: @MichelaBonizzi - In 2.1.9 and 2.1.10, the setting of strictSql seems to be irrelevant.  Could you please modify your answer accordingly?

Comment: @peak before posting my answer i've made some tests with positive results using that command instead without it I got some errors, anyway this command could be useful for someone else that has earlier versions.

Comment: @MichelaBonizzi  - I ran tests in 2.1.9 and 2.1.10. Which version of ODB were you using?

Comment: @peak I ran tests in 2.1.9

Comment: @michelabonizzi - I think maybe you made a mistake.  See also @Lvca's answer. Here is a transcript using OrientDB console v.2.1.9-SNAPSHOT (build 2.1.x@r; 2016-01-07 10:51:24+0000) showing that the setting is irrelevant:
```> ALTER DATABASE custom strictSql=true
Database updated successfully

> select `from` from purchases
----+------
#   |@CLASS
----+------
0   |null  
1   |null  
----+------

2 item(s) found. 

> ALTER DATABASE custom strictSql=false
> select `from` from purchases
----+------
#   |@CLASS
----+------
0   |null  
1   |null  
----+------

2 item(s) found.
```

Answer (score 2):

FROM and TO are reserved words. So you could just change the name or backtick them. Example:

```
select `from` from Activity
```